# After vs when…which makes more sense?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

I’d like to know whether it makes more sense to use “after” or “when” in the following sentence:

> The two have their first meeting on the highway after Sasha’s car breaks down and John stops to help her.

> The two have their first meeting on the highway when Sasha’s car breaks down and John stops to help her.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely prefer "after." This is a style recommendation rather than a grammatical recommendation. There is nothing wrong grammatically with "when," but I greatly doubt it describes exactly what you intend.

Did you mean that, while her radiator is exploding, her hood is flying into the sky, and she is trying not to wreck, she will lower her window and say while driving by John, "Hi, my name is Sasha. What's your name?" I doubt that is the scene that you are trying to describe. (If it is, use "while" rather than "when." If you are describing what happened after the breakdonm, then use "after.")

"When" may mean "while" or "after." Good style suggests using the more exact word, either "while" or "after," depending on what you actually mean.

I admit that style is a matter of opinion, but it is so easy in English to avoid ambiguity that it seems to me to be worth doing so.

Comment: I, on the other hand, would fin d it more natural to use _when_ (in the sense of _on the occasion that_).

Comment: @KateBunting I did say that it was a matter of style, and there is a subjective element to all questions of style. I just dislike the ambiguity in “when” in those cases where there is reason to distinguish between “while concurrently “ and “immediately after.” Obviously, in any case for which that distinction is immaterial, I too might use “when.” Possibly I was a bit too dogmatic.